# using Int or number in Elm dictionary

Tags: haskell, dictionary, integer, int, elm

I defined my model to be `Model = Dict Int String` however in compile time, I get `number` instead of `Int` so it is wrong:

```
The 2nd argument to function `get` is causing a mismatch.

71|              Dict.get 3 model 
                            ^^^^^
Function `get` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:

    Dict number v

But it is:

    Model
```

and unfortunately Elm repl does the same thing returning `Dict number` instead of `Dict Int`.

```
> Dict.fromList [ (1, {a= 1} )]
Dict.fromList [(1,{ a = 1 })] : Dict.Dict number { a : number1 }
```

Certain languages such as Haskell expose `Int` as as well as `Integer` as well as `number`  How can I coerce it to be integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would you be able to provide the relevant code?

The following compiles and works fine for me:

```
import Dict exposing (Dict, fromList, get)

type alias Model = Dict Int String

model : Model
model = fromList [(1, "apple"), (2, "banana"), (42, "giraffe")]

test : Maybe String
test = get 2 model
```

Comment: The essential part of the answer above is that the `Model` is defined as a `Dict` alias.

Please make sure your model definition is using `alias` keyword. Otherwise you define your Model as a single case discriminated union.

    `type alias Model = Dict Int String`